# IOS reuse AudioQueueBuffer

Tags: ios, audioqueue, audioqueueservices

I have found in many examples of AudioQueue, we always read audiofilepackets, and copy the audiodata to the inBuffer in callback function.

I want to read audioData into my buffers at sometime before the audioQueueStart, and repeat the buffer continously without copying any data, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes I found the AudioQueue doesn't clear the mAudioData field in the inBuffer, this question is stupid. I preload my buffers and just call the AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer function